# Catching keyboard events on window does not get special characters right

Tags: javascript

This script is supposed to catch key presses. But it is getting special characters wrongly received. For example, pressing `\` results in `Ü`.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownCallback, false);

function keydownCallback(e) {
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode) {
        console.log("Character typed: " + String.fromCharCode(charCode));
    }
}
```

Is there any way in which I can get the input characters correct?

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated.  Try `key`

Comment: use `e.key` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`KeyBoardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) e.g. in your case `e.key` would be `"\"` when the backslash is pressed.

Comment: Event.key is not supported by Safari/WebKit. :-(